# Outputted JSON file repeats array name (VB.NET, Newtonsoft.JSON)

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, json.net

I am new to JSON and trying to create a JSON output identical to this using VB.NET and Newtonsoft.JSON

```
{
  "name": "trash",
  "icon": "trash_can",
  "display_name": "Taking out the trash",
  "display": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Craft a Trash Can"
    },
    {
      "type": "recipe",
      "query": "trash_can"
    }
  ],
  "conditions": [
    {
      "type": "item",
      "item": "trash_can",
      "amount": 1
    }
  ],
  "rewards": [
    {
      "type": "item",
      "item": "cobblestone",
      "amount": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I have written so far outputs this:

```
  "name": "trash",
  "icon": "trash_can",
  "display_name": "Taking out the Trash",
  "display": {
    "display": [
      {
        "type": "item",
        "text": "Craft a Trash Can"
      }
    ]
  },
  "conditions": {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "item",
        "item": "trash_can",
        "amount": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "rewards": {
    "rewards": [
      {
        "type": "item",
        "item": "cobblestone",
        "amount": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My output repeats the terms "display," "conditions," and "rewards."

My code is as follows:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim quest = New Quest()

        quest.Title = "trash"
        quest.Icon = "trash_can"
        quest.displayName = "Taking out the Trash"

        Dim varDisplay = New Display()
        varDisplay.Type = "item"
        varDisplay.Text = "Craft a Trash Can"
        quest.display.displayItems.Add(varDisplay)

        Dim varCondition = New Condition()
        varCondition.Type = "item"
        varCondition.Item = "trash_can"
        quest.conditions.conditionItems.Add(varCondition)

        Dim varReward = New Reward()
        varReward.Type = "item"
        varReward.Item = "cobblestone"
        varReward.Amount = 1
        quest.rewards.rewardItems.Add(varReward)

        Dim rawJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quest)

        Dim output As System.IO.StreamWriter
        output = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Application.StartupPath & "/trash.json", True)
        output.Write(rawJSON)
        output.Close()


    End Sub
End Class

Class Quest
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="name")>
    Public Property Title As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="icon")>
    Public Property Icon As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="display_name")>
    Public Property displayName As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="display")>
    Public Property display As DisplayItems = New DisplayItems

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="conditions")>
    Public Property conditions As ConditionItems = New ConditionItems

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="rewards")>
    Public Property rewards As RewardItems = New RewardItems
End Class

Public Class Display
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="type")>
    Public Property Type As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="text")>
    Public Property Text As String
End Class

Public Class DisplayItems
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="display")>
    Public Property displayItems As List(Of Display) = New List(Of Display)
End Class

Public Class Condition
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="type")>
    Public Property Type As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="item")>
    Public Property Item As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="amount")>
    Public Property Amount As Integer
End Class

Public Class ConditionItems
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="conditions")>
    Public Property conditionItems As List(Of Condition) = New List(Of Condition)
End Class

Public Class Reward
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="type")>
    Public Property Type As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="item")>
    Public Property Item As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="amount")>
    Public Property Amount As Integer
End Class

Public Class RewardItems
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="rewards")>
    Public Property rewardItems As List(Of Reward) = New List(Of Reward)
End Class
```

Any help or advice on removing those items and leaving just the arrays would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is the way how you are populating those display, rewards and conditions collections. Per your code, this is the structure you have (same explanation goes for rewards and conditions):

```
Quest
|
|
|--DisplayItems (with json proerty set to display)
    |
    |
    |--- collection of Display (again, used the same json proerty name display)
```

What you need is this:

```
Quest
|
|
|--- collection of Display (use the json proerty name display here as its camel casing)
```

You can try removing DisplayItems class by directly having

```
<JsonProperty(PropertyName:="display")>
Public Property displayItems As List(Of Display) = New List(Of Display)
```

under Quest. Same explanation goes for others (conditions and rewards) as well.

So, please modify your Quest class as below:

```
Class Quest
       ....
<JsonProperty(PropertyName:="display")>
Public Property displayItems As List(Of Display) = New List(Of Display)
       .....
End Class
```

and then modify your button click as below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         ......

        Dim varDisplay = New Display With {.Type = "item", .Text = "Craft a Trash Can"}
        quest.displayItems.Add(varDisplay)

        ..........    
    End Sub
End Class
```